# How to create blue horizontal line in EditText Android

Tags: android

As in my question title, is it a default theme in Android or I need to do it manually? I want to have it from Froyo devices and above. Any guideline or hint to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for the Holo theme for older Android versions than 3.0? If you do, then take look at the library HoloEverywhere: https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Many developers use it and it does exactly what you expect.

Comment: but it also very huge for small projects

Comment: Yes pavko_a, I'm agree with you.. The projects are very big.. Btw, I am a bit confused how to add it to my project because I don't use git..